# Change pipe delimited file to comma delimited in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a pipe delimited .TXT file. I need to change the delimiter to a comma instead but still keep the file extension as .TXT. The file looks like this:

Column 1   |Column 2

13|2019-09-30

96|2019-09-26

173|2019-09-25

I am using Windows Powershell 5.1 version for my script.

I am using the following code:

```
$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg "c:\file.txt"
$outstream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "c:\out.txt"
while ($line = $file.ReadLine()) {
$s = $line -replace '|', ','
$outstream.WriteLine($s)
}
$file.close()
$outstream.close()
```

Instead of just replacing the pipe with a comma, the output file looks like this:

C,o,l,u,m,n, 1 ,  |,C,o,l,u,m,n, 2

1,3,|,2,0,1,9,-,0,9,-,3,0

9,6,|2,0,1,9,-,0,9,-,2,6

1,7,3,|,2,0,1,9,-,0,9,-,2,5

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with your answer is in how you try to replace the `|` characters in the input:

> `$s = $line -replace '|', ','       # WRONG`

**PowerShell's `-replace` operator expects a *regex* (regular expression)** as its first RHS operand, and `|` is a regex metacharacter (has special meaning)<sup>[1]</sup>; to **use it as a *literal* character**, you **must `\`-escape** it:

```
# '\'-escape regex metacharacter '|' to treat it literally.
$s = $line -replace '\|', ','
```

While [PowerShell's `-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) is very flexible, **in simple cases such as this one you can alternatively use the `[string]` type's `.Replace()` method**, which performs *literal* string replacements and therefore doesn't require escaping (it's also faster than `-replace`):

```
# Use literal string replacement.
# Note: .Replace() is case-*sensitive*, unlike -replace
$s = $line.Replace('|', ',')
```

---

<sup>[1] `|` denotes an *alternation* in a regex, meaning that the subexpressions on either side are matched against the input string and one of them matching is sufficient; if your full regex is just `|`, it effectively matches the *empty string before and after each character* in the input, which explains your symptom; e.g., `'foo' -replace '|', '@'` yields `@f@o@o@`</sup>

Comment: This is a very good explanation, and also applies to `-split` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @JeffZeitlin; yes, your `-split` / `-join` combo definitely works too, and the points about `-replace` vs. `.Replace()` apply analogously to `-split` vs. `.Split()`.

Comment: Thank you! Escaping makes sense and worked beautifully. I tried .Replace() as well, and that did it a couple second quicker than the -replace with escape.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @Arijita. Allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment:

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` by specifying the `-Delimiter`.

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Path "c:\file.txt" | Export-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Path "c:\file.txt" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `Export-CSV` will generate a bogus line at the top of the file, unless you include the `-NoTypeInformation` switch.  But also see my comment to @StanislavCastek with my answer.

Comment: Thank you! (I was avoiding this way since it is a huge file and this takes a while to finish. )

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, You are correct, I always forget to include `-NoTypeInformation` initially. I've updated the answer to include that. @Arijita, that's a fair observation, AFAIK `Import-Csv` is parsing it into an object in memory before `Export-Csv` converts it back to CSV. So consider this the easy method, but definately not the most performant approach.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6) and [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-6) operators to be of interest.

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\File.TXT" | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split "\|") -join "," } | Set-Content -Path "C:\Out.TXT"
```

Comment: Down voted because answer provided earlier by @Jacob is more effective

Comment: @StanislavCastek - If you try Jacob's solution _as written_, there will be a problem - at the very least, a bogus line generated at the top of the file. While structurally, what the querent posted _appears_ to be conformant with a bog-standard CSV, I _never_ assume that posted sample data is in perfect conformance with reality; if there are other lines in the file that do not match the two-column CSV model, the `Import-CSV`/`Export-CSV` model will fail - whereas mine won't. _If_ the original file is perfectly CSV-conformant as the sample shows, I will concede that Jacob's solution is faster.

Comment: @StanislavCastek - Had the querent _specifically_ stated that the original file was a CSV (regardless of the file name), I would have proposed Jacob's solution with the necessary correction.

Comment: In that vein (+1): Even if you use the `-NoTypeInformation` switch, there is another potential complication (which again won't matter if the input file is well-formed and all that matters is whether the output is a valid CSV file): `Export-Csv` will invariably _double-quote_ all field values.